# does $\int ^1_0 \frac {\ln x}{1-x^2}\ \mathrm dx$ - converge?

Tags: calculus

**Question:**

$\int ^1_0 \frac {\ln x}{1-x^2}dx$ - converges or diverges?

**What we did:**

We tried to compare with $-\frac 1x$ and $-\frac 1{x-1}$ but ended up finding that these convergence tests fail. Our book says this integral diverges, but Wolfram on the other hand says it converges. How come?

Comment: I think the book is wrong. First compare the integrand to $\log x$ near $x=0$; then see what happens to the integrand near $x=1$.

Comment: You might be interested in this question it doesn't tackle convergence as such but there are some nice ways of evaluating the integral itself http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537903/proving-int-01-frac-lnxx2-1dx-frac-pi28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two potential sources of divergence if the integral were to diverge (it doesn't): at $x=0$ and $x=1$.  At $x=0$, the integral behaves as $\ln{x}$, which has antiderivative $x \ln{x}-x$.  You may show that the limit of this expression as $x \to 0$ is $0$ using e.g.,L'Hopital.  So the integrand is integrable at $x=0$.

At $x=1$, you may show that

$$\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{\ln{x}}{1-x^2} = -\frac12$$

so that the integrand is integrable here as well.  Thus, the integral converges.

Comment: Hi. Thank you very much for the answer, It really helped. One last question about your way- when x=1 did you use the limit comparison test with g(x)=1 (which converges) and that's how you got your limit that equaled -0.5?

Comment: @user1685224: I used the fact that $\ln{x} \sim x-1$ as $x \to 1$.

Answer (score 0):

It converges and its value is $-\pi^2/8$.

Comment: $-\frac{\pi^2}8$

Comment: I am not sure how this could be of any interest. If you change variable x = Exp[y], your integrand becomes "-y Csch[y] dy", to be integrated between minus infinity and zero. The antiderivative is not very complex. As mentioned by Lucian, the value of the integral is (- Pi^2 / 8)

Comment: To be a complete answer you need to say *why*...