# How prove this $I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x}\ln{\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2}dx=\pi^2$

Tags: integration

Prove this 
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}\ln{\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2}dx=\pi^2$$

My try: let
$$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{2\ln{(1+x)}}{x}-\dfrac{2\ln{|(1-x)|}}{x}dx$$

Comment: The square is causing me some confusion. Do you mean $\left(\ln y\right)^2$ or $\ln\left(y^2\right)$?

Comment: @Katsu If $u(x) = \ln(1+x)$ then $u'(x) = \frac{1}{x+1}$.

Comment: @Katsu Your corrected hint is no longer a hint, but an unrelated fact. The integral of $\frac{\ln(1\pm x)}{x}$ is non-trivial and requires the dilog function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm#Dilogarithm

Comment: @Fly by Night: I guess square is inside log because he deducts that $ln(y²)=2.ln(y)$

Comment: @FlybyNight It's difficult to provide an answer when the OP refuses to answer your comment. So, we have to make a "guess" which is not a mathematical trick.

Comment: @Katsu It's very common in ${\tt M.SE}$ that people don't use $\left(\,\,\,\right)$'s. They write $\sin x$ instead of $\sin\left(x\right)$...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is an approach. Using the change of variables $\frac{1+x}{1-x}=y$ gives

$$ I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}\ln{\left(\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2\right)}dx=2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\ln(y^2)}{1-y^2}dy=8\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln y}{1-y^2}dy $$

$$ = 8\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{1} y^{2k} \ln y\, dy = 8\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2} = 8.\frac{\pi^2}{8} = \pi^2.$$

Comment: Mhenni Benghorbal   well done  +1

Comment: @mert: Thanks for the comment. I really appreciate it.

Comment: This is a very nice argument, but it changes one problem in to another. You can't just *assume* that

$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(2k+1)^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{8}$$

as you have done here. Proving this summation is far from trivial. (The summation identity can be proven, for example, using Fourier Series, but you must justify the summation result.)

Comment: @FlybyNight: Thanks for the comment. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Downvoter: Can we know why the downvote?

Answer (score 5):

First perform the bilinear transformation:
$$x={\frac {1-t}{t+1}}$$
to get:
$$\int _{0}^{\infty }\!\ln  \left( {\frac { \left( 1+x \right) ^{2}}{
 \left( 1-x \right) ^{2}}} \right)\dfrac{1}{x} {dx}=4\,\int _{0}^{1}\!{
\frac {\ln  \left( {t}^{2} \right) }{{t}^{2}-1}}{dt}=8\,\int _{0}^{1}\!{
\frac {\ln  \left(t \right) }{{t}^{2}-1}}{dt} $$
then, [from this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537903/proving-int-01-frac-lnxx2-1dx-frac-pi28/538094#538094), consider the integral:
$$I(m)=\int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac {  \ln\left( t \right)  ^{m-1}}{
{t}^{2}-1}}{dt} \quad:\quad \mathfrak{R}(m)>1 $$
and the substitution $t=e^{-u}$:
$$\begin{aligned}
\int _{0}^{1}\!{\frac {  \ln\left( t \right)  ^{m-1}}{
{t}^{2}-1}}{dt}=& \left( -1 \right) ^{m-1}\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {
{u}^{m-1}{{\rm e}^{-u}}}{-1+{{\rm e}^{-2\,u}}}}{du}\\
=&\left( -1 \right) ^{m-1}
\int _{0}^{\infty }\!-{\frac {{u}^{m-1}}{-1+{{\rm e}^{u}}}}+{\frac {{u
}^{m-1}}{-1+{{\rm e}^{2\,u}}}}{du}\\
=&\left( -1 \right) ^{m-1}\left( 
1- \dfrac{1}{2^m} \right) 
\int _{0}^{\infty }\!{\frac {{u}^{m-1}}{-1+{{\rm e}^{u}}}}{du}\\
=&\left( -1 \right) ^{m}\left( 
1- \dfrac{1}{2^m} \right) 
\Gamma  \left( m \right) \zeta  \left( m \right) 
\end{aligned}$$
where we have used [Riemann's integral representation of the zeta function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537903/proving-int-01-frac-lnxx2-1dx-frac-pi28/538094#538094) and we also made the substitution $u\rightarrow\frac{u}{2}$ in the second term of the second line to pass to line three (having noted that convergence of both terms individually is assured by comparison with Riemanns integral).

One way to evaluate the Riemann zeta function at even integers is to use the Fourier series for Bernoulli polynomials. For example, calculating the Fourier series for the second Bernoulli polynomial tells you that:
$$\displaystyle{x}^{2}-x+1/6=\frac{1}{\pi^2}\sum _{n=1}^{\infty }{\frac {\cos \left( nx \right) }{{n
}^{2}}}\quad : \quad-\pi<x<\pi$$

and evaluating this series at $x=0$ then tells you that $\zeta(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$ which together with $\Gamma(2)=1!=1$ leads to: $$I(2)=\frac{\pi^2}{8}$$ and the result follows.

Comment: This is a very nice argument, but you glibly use the fact that $\zeta(2) = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$. The OP needs to be able to both know , and also justify, why the following is true:

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k^2} = \frac{\pi^2}{6}$$

You need to justify this identity for this answer to be valid.

Answer (score 3):

We can use an argument from Complex Analysis and the calculation of the integral is pretty simple and neat. Note that
$$ \arctan z=\frac{1}{2i}\ln\frac{i-z}{i+z}. $$
So we have
$$ \ln\frac{1+x}{1-x}=\ln\frac{i+ix}{i-ix}=-\ln\frac{i-ix}{i+ix}=-2i\arctan(ix) $$
and hence
\begin{eqnarray}
I&=&\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}\ln{\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2}dx\\
&=&2\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}\ln{\left(\dfrac{1+x}{1-x}\right)}dx\\
&=&-4i\int_{0}^{\infty}\dfrac{1}{x}\arctan(ix)dx\\
&=&-4i\left(\arctan(ix)\ln x\bigg|_0^\infty-\int_0^\infty\frac{i\ln x}{-x^2+1}dx\right)\\
&=&4\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{x^2-1}dx=-8\int_0^1\frac{\ln x}{1-x^2}dx\\
&=&-8\int_0^1\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^{2n}\ln xdx=-8\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2n+1)^n}\\
&=&\pi^2.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: +1) Introducing $\arctan$ is indeed a nice trick. You might want to justify the last integral to make this answer more complete though.

Comment: @Superabound, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Allow me to present an approach that uses dilogarithms. Split the integral up into 2 and substitute $x \mapsto \dfrac{1}{x}$ for the second integral. This yields
\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2dx
&=\int^1_0\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2dx+\int^\infty_1\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^2dx\\
&=4\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1+x)-\ln(1-x)}{x}dx\\
&=4\left(\operatorname{Li}_2(1)-\operatorname{Li}_2(-1)\right)\\
&=4\left(\frac{\pi^2}{6}+\frac{\pi^2}{12}\right)\\
&=\pi^2
\end{align}

Comment: Nice solution. +1. BTW, instead of introducing dilogarithm function I think it would be better to use series expansion like this [OP](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/890872/123277).