# Solving an 8th degree polynomial

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

I know that through the Abel Ruffini Theorem the general solution to a polynomial of degree five or more cannot be found explicitly. But are there are any other ways to find the roots of such a polynomial besides exhaustive methods like Newton's Method? The question of finding such roots arose when trying to find the the y maximum of the unit lemniscate.

Comment: I like the rational root test.  By Gauss' Lemma it finds all the integer roots as well.

Comment: If there's a bunch of symmetry then there are some simple ways to deduce such roots; I do exactly this in evaluating the following integral: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562694/integral-int-11-frac1x-sqrt-frac1x1-x-ln-left-frac2-x22-x1/565626#565626

Comment: The for this specific polynomial $x^8 -2x^6 +3x^4 -2x^2 +1=0$, the test does give me rational zeroes but I don't think these are the ones I need. I'm trying to find the maximum y coordinate of the unit lemniscate so letting x=1 would not get me the correct answer because the maximum y occurs between x=0 and x=1.

Comment: @RyanMcGaha:  Under the transform $x^2 \rightarrow u$ this is a fourth degree polynomial, so Abel-Ruffini is not an obstruction.  (Additionally, the polynomial's roots are various sixth roots of -1.)

Comment: @RyanMcGaha It would be useful if you put the polynomial in the question, because the one you have is a symmetric polynomial of degree $4$ in $y=x^2$, which can be reduced to a quadratic in $y+\frac 1y$. In short, it can be solved in a standard way by solving a chain of three quadratic equations. If you put it in the question, people will be able to show you the steps you need to take.

Comment: Oh wow. I did not see that. I knew the roots were plus or minus the sixth root of i. I used wolfram alpha but I wanted to know how to get there not just the answer and it could not provide the step by step solution. I'll try this substitution. Thank you.