# Closed form for limit of a sum $\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}(\ln m-4\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{2n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^{k}k\ln k)\approx-0.092$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, summation, riemann-zeta

I'm looking for a closed form of

$$\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\left(\ln m-4\sum_{n=1}^{m}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{n}}{2n+1}\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\left(-1\right)^{k}k\ln k\right)\approx-0.092$$

for even $m$.

(*For context this is a continuation of my ongoing work from this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1309701/does-int-11-frac-arctan-x-textarctanh-x-mathrmdx-have-a-closed/3593832#3593832)*.)

Here's what I've tried so far. Wolfram alpha gives gives me

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\left(-1\right)^{k}k\ln k=-2\zeta^{(1,0)}\left(-1,n+\frac{1}{2}\right)+2\zeta^{(1,0)}\left(-1,n+1\right)+n\ln2+3\ln A-\frac{1}{12}\ln2-\frac{1}{4}$$

From [Wolfram's function site](https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/Zeta2/20/01/01/01/03/) I get

$$\zeta^{(1,0)}(-1,x)=-\frac{1}{12}\left(-6x^{2}+18x-12\left(x-1\right)\ln\left(x-1\right)+12\ln A+6\left(x-1\right)\ln2\pi-13\right)+\psi^{(-2)}\left(x-1\right)$$

Combining these gets me

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\left(-1\right)^{k}k\ln k=-2\psi^{(-2)}\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)+2\psi^{(-2)}\left(n\right)-\left(2n-1\right)\ln\left(n-\frac{1}{2}\right)+2n\ln n+n+n\ln2-\frac{1}{2}\ln2\pi+3\ln A-\frac{1}{12}\ln2-1$$

I could keep trying to find more expressions, but it feels like this is making things more complicated and possibly going to bring me back where I started.

Comment: Was there any context for the problem, or origin with more clues?

Comment: It seems that you did not use the whole formula of Wolfram

Comment: The limit [does not exist](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3qsuhbjptp).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have
$$
\zeta ( - 1,n + 1) =  - \frac{1}{2}n^2  - \frac{1}{2}n - \frac{1}{{12}}
$$
and
\begin{align*}
\zeta ^{(1,0)} ( - 1,n + 1) = \zeta ^{(1,0)} ( - 1,n) & + n\log n =  - \frac{1}{4}n^2  + \left( {\frac{1}{2}n^2  + \frac{1}{2}n + \frac{1}{{12}}} \right)\log n + \frac{1}{{12}} \\ & - \int_0^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{1}{{e^t  - 1}} - \frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{t}{{12}}} \right)t^{ - 2} e^{ - nt} dt} 
\end{align*}
(cf. https://doi.org/10.1098/rspa.2017.0363). Noting that
$$
\zeta ^{(1,0)} \left( { - 1,n + \tfrac{1}{2}} \right) = \frac{{\log 2}}{2}\zeta ( - 1,2n + 1) + \frac{1}{2}\zeta ^{(1,0)} ( - 1,2n + 1) - \zeta ^{(1,0)} ( - 1,n + 1),
$$
we derive
\begin{align*}
 & \sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {( - 1)^k k\log k}  = n\log (2n) + \frac{1}{4}\log n + 3\log A - \frac{{\log 2}}{{12}} \\ & + \int_0^{ + \infty } {\left( {\frac{1}{{e^t  - 1}} - \frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{t}{{12}}} \right)t^{ - 2} \left( {e^{ - 2nt}  - 4e^{ - nt} } \right)dt} .
\end{align*}
Thus, after some tedious calculations, we arrive at
\begin{align*}
& \mathop {\lim }\limits_{m \to  + \infty } \left( {\log (2m) - 4\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{2m} {\frac{{( - 1)^n }}{{2n + 1}}\sum\limits_{k = 1}^{2n} {( - 1)^k k\log k} } } \right)
\\ &
 = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{m \to  + \infty } \left[ {\log (2m) - 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{2m} {( - 1)^n \log n} } \right] \\ & + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n \log n}}{{2n + 1}}}  + \left( {3\log A - \frac{{7\log 2}}{{12}}} \right)(4 - \pi )
\\ &
 + \int_0^{ + \infty } \!\! \left( {\frac{1}{{e^t  - 1}} - \frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{t}{{12}}} \right)t^{ - 2} \! \left( {16e^{\frac{t}{2}} \arctan (e^{ - \frac{t}{2}} ) - 4e^t \arctan (e^{ - t} ) - 12} \right)dt .
\end{align*}
Therefore, it remains to obtain a closed expression for
$$
\mathop {\lim }\limits_{m \to  + \infty } \left[ {\log (2m) - 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{2m} {( - 1)^n \log n} } \right].
$$
Some algebraic manipulation and Stirling's formula give
\begin{align*}
& \log (2m) - 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{2m} {( - 1)^n \log n}  =  - \log (2m) + 2\sum\limits_{n = 1}^{m - 1} {\log \left( {\frac{{2n + 1}}{{2n}}} \right)} \\ & =  - \log (2m) + 2\log \left( {\frac{{(2m - 1)!!}}{{(2m - 2)!!}}} \right) \to  \log \left( {\frac{2 }{\pi}} \right).
\end{align*}
Accordingly, a closed form expression for your limit is given by
\begin{align*}
&  \log \left( {\frac{2 }{\pi}} \right) + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  {\frac{{( - 1)^n \log n}}{{2n + 1}}}  + \left( {3\log A - \frac{{7\log 2}}{{12}}} \right)(4 - \pi )
\\ &
 + \int_0^{ + \infty } \!\! \left( {\frac{1}{{e^t  - 1}} - \frac{1}{t} + \frac{1}{2} - \frac{t}{{12}}} \right)t^{ - 2} \! \left( {16e^{\frac{t}{2}} \arctan (e^{ - \frac{t}{2}} ) - 4e^t \arctan (e^{ - t} ) - 12} \right)dt .
\end{align*}
The numerical value I got form this formula is $-0.09222744\ldots$. Using the formula
$$
\log n = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{{e^{ - t}  - e^{ - nt} }}{t}dt} ,
$$
one can derive the quickly convergent integral representation
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^\infty  { \frac{{( - 1)^n\log n}}{{2n + 1}}}  = \int_0^{ + \infty } {\frac{1}{t}\left( {\left( {\frac{\pi }{4} - 1} \right)e^{ - t}  - e^{\frac{t}{2}} \arctan  ( e^{ - \frac{t}{2}}  ) + 1} \right)dt} .
$$

Answer (score 1):

*I do not know if this could be of any help*.

For large values of $x$, we have
$$\zeta ^{(1,0)}(-1,x)=x^2 \left(\frac{\log (x)}{2}-\frac{1}{4}\right)-\frac{1}{2} x \log
   (x)+\frac{1}{12} (\log (x)+1)+$$ $$\frac{1}{720 x^2}-\frac{1}{5040
   x^4}+\frac{1}{10080 x^6}-\frac{1}{9504
   x^8}+\frac{691}{3603600 x^{10}}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^{12}}\right)$$ Using your fiirst formula, this would give
$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\left(-1\right)^{k}k\ln k=n \log (2 n)+\frac{1}{4}\log (n)+\left(3 \log (A)-\frac{\log (2)}{12}\right)+\frac{1}{192 n^2}-$$ $$\frac{1}{1280 n^4}+\frac{17}{43008 n^6}-\frac{31}{73728
   n^8}+\frac{691}{901120 n^{10}}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^{12}}\right)$$ which is almost exact even for small values of $n$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
n & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 5 & 12.603993216766530412 & 12.603993216758928837 \\
 10 & 31.221522180442592703 & 31.221522180442590647 \\
 15 & 52.383497574013162289 & 52.383497574013162273 \\
 20 & 75.215036332678595144 & 75.215036332678595144
\end{array}
\right)$$