# Evalaute $\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}{1\over x}\sqrt{\alpha+x\over \alpha-x}\ln^n\left({\alpha+x\over \alpha-x}\right)\mathrm dx=(-\pi)^{n+1}F(n)$

Tags: calculus, integration

**Proposed:**

$$\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}{x^k}\sqrt{\alpha+x\over \alpha-x}\ln^n\left({\alpha+x\over \alpha-x}\right)\mathrm dx=F(k,n)\tag1$$

Let $k=-1$ and $F(-1,n)=F(n)$

> $$\int_{-\alpha}^{\alpha}{1\over x}\sqrt{\alpha+x\over \alpha-x}\ln^n\left({\alpha+x\over \alpha-x}\right)\mathrm dx=(-\pi)^{n+1}F(n)\tag2$$
>   Where $n,\alpha\ge1$

We have the following

$n=1\implies$ $F(1)=1$

$n=2\implies$ $F(2)=-1$

$n=3\implies$ $F(3)=2$

$n=4\implies$ $F(4)=-5$

$n=5\implies$ $F(5)=16$

$n=6\implies$ $F(6)=-61$

**How can we find the closed form of $(2)?$**

$u={\alpha+x\over \alpha-x}\implies dx={(\alpha-x)^2\over 2\alpha}$

$x=\alpha\cdot{u-1\over u+1}$

$(\alpha-x)^2={4\alpha^2\over (u+1)^2}$

$(2)\implies$

$$2\int_{0}^{\infty}{\sqrt{u}\over u^2-1}\cdot\ln^n(u)\mathrm du\tag3$$

$$....$$

Comment: Very much reminds me of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/562694/integral-int-11-frac1x-sqrt-frac1x1-x-ln-left-frac2-x22-x1).

Comment: First of all, the $\alpha$ is irrelevant:

$$\int_{-\alpha}^{+\alpha}{x^k}\sqrt{\alpha+x\over \alpha-x}\ln^n\left({\alpha+x\over \alpha-x}\right)~\mathrm dx=\alpha^{k+1}\int_{-1}^{+1}x^k\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\ln^n\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)~\mathrm dx$$

Secondly, consider this integral:

$$I_k(t)=\int_{-1}^{+1}x^k\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^t~\mathrm dx$$

and note that

$$\frac{\partial I_k(t)}{\partial t^n}\bigg|_{t=1/2}=\int_{-1}^{+1}x^k\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\ln^n\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)~\mathrm dx$$

Those are my thoughts :-)

Comment: I dont know if it helps but a good start would be $x=a\cos (u) $

Comment: Oops, it should be $\frac{\partial^nI_k(t)}{\partial t^n}$ at the end there.

Comment: It is full of integrals with irrelevant parameters here on MSE. If you want to ask about $\int_{0}^{1}\frac{u^{1/2}\log^n(u)}{1-u^2}\,du$, just ask about it, but please add your attempts, since this integral can be tackled by the same techniques solving a good $95\%$ of your questions.

Comment: Sorry everyone I ask a wrong question. I was looking for the closed form of (2) not (1)

Comment: Mr jack I have been here on MSE for almost 8 months, wasting a lot of time. Anyway see you in the future when I get my degree in maths.

Comment: @Jackiechan, I don't consider this a waste of time.

Comment: Thank you @Zaid Alyafeai, soon it comes to an end here for me. Wish you all the best in the future. Thank once again.

Comment: @Jackiechan, you just need to do what feels good for you. If you enjoy what you are doing then continue it regardless of what people think. Wish you the best.

Answer (score 1):

The comment of Simply Beautiful Art gives a big hint on how to proceed. I cannot give a general formula to (1), although it is possible albeit complicated.

Let $$I(k,t)=\int_{-1}^{+1}x^k\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)^t dx \quad\quad J(k,n)=\int_{-1}^{+1}x^k\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\ln^n\left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)dx$$
making $u = \frac{1+x}{1-x}$ gives 
$$I(k,t) = 2\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^t(u-1)^k}{(u+1)^{2+k}} dx$$

When $k$ is a positive integer, we can expand and note that $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{u^a}{(u+1)^b} du = B(a+1,b-a-1)$$ with the beta function.

Since the derivative of gamma function at half-integer value can be calculated, the closed form for each $J(k,n)$ can also be found.

For instances

---

$$J(1,1) = 2\pi \quad J(2,1) = \frac{5\pi}{3} \quad J(2,1) = \frac{5\pi}{3} \quad \\ J(4,1) = \frac{89\pi}{60} \quad J(5,1) = \frac{89\pi}{60} \quad J(6,1) = \frac{381\pi}{280}$$

---

$$\begin{aligned}
J(1,2) = J(2,2) = 4\pi + \frac{\pi^3}{2} \\
J(3,2) = J(4,2) = \frac{14\pi}{3} + \frac{3\pi^3}{8} \\
J(5,2) = J(6,2) = \frac{439\pi}{90} + \frac{5\pi^3}{16} \\
\end{aligned}$$

---

$$\begin{aligned}
J(1,3) & = 6\pi^3 \\
J(2,3) &= J(3,3) = 8\pi + 5\pi^3 \\
J(4,3) &= J(5,3) = 12\pi + \frac{89\pi^3}{20} \\
\end{aligned}$$