# Integral $\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\ln(2x^2+2x+1)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}} \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I was trying to solve one of the famous integrals on this site:

$$I=\int_{-1}^1\frac1x\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}}\ln\left(\frac{2x^2+2x+1}{2x^2-2x+1}\right) \mathrm dx$$

I was able to reduce it to the form:

$$I=2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\ln(2x^2+2x+1)}{x\sqrt{1-x^2}} \mathrm dx$$

I have verified that both the integrals are matching.
But I am unable to figure it out after this.
In the original post I didn't see a similar approach to this.

Comment: [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/667576/170231) to the post in question is essentially what you have. Rewrite $\tanh^{-1}$ in terms of logarithms and simplify to get your integral.

Comment: @user170231 Thank you for the link, I seem to have missed that answer as I haven't dealt with inverse hyperbolic trigonometric functions.