# The other ways to calculate $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x}dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Prove that
>   $$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x}dx=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$
>   **without** using series expansion.

---

An easy way to calculate the above integral is using series expansion. Here is an example
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x}dx&=-\int_0^1\frac{1}{x}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{x^{2n}}{n} dx\\
&=-\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n}\int_0^1x^{2n-1}dx\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{1}{n^2}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}
\end{align}
I am wondering, are there other ways to calculate the integral **without** using series expansion of its integrand? Any method is welcome. Thank you. (>‿◠)✌

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After substituting $y=x^2$, we obtain
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x}\ dx=\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-y)}{y}\ dy
$$
Using the fact that
$$
\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}=-\int_0^1\frac{1}{1-xy}\ dy
$$
then
$$
\frac12\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}\ dx=-\frac12\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^1\frac{1}{1-xy}\ dy\ dx.
$$
Using transformation variable by setting $(u,v)=\left(\frac{x+y}{2},\frac{x-y}{2}\right)$ so that $(x,y)=(u-v,u+v)$ and its [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant) is equal to $2$. Therefore
$$
-\frac12\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^1\frac{1}{1-xy}\ dy\ dx=-\iint_A\frac{du\ dv}{1-u^2+v^2},
$$
where $A$ is the square with vertices $(0,0),\left(\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\right), (1,0),$ and $\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2}\right)$. Exploiting the symmetry of the square, we obtain
$$
\begin{align}
\iint_A\frac{du\ dv}{1-u^2+v^2}=\ &2\int_{u=0}^{\Large\frac12}\int_{v=0}^u\frac{dv\ du}{1-u^2+v^2}+2\int_{u=\Large\frac12}^1\int_{v=0}^{1-u}\frac{dv\ du}{1-u^2+v^2}\\
=\ &2\int_{u=0}^{\Large\frac12}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\right)\ du\\
&+2\int_{u=\Large\frac12}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\arctan\left(\frac{1-u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\right)\ du.
\end{align}
$$
Since $\arctan\left(\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\right)=\arcsin u$, and if $\theta=\arctan\left(\frac{1-u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\right)$ then $\tan^2\theta=\frac{1-u}{1+u}$ and $\sec^2\theta=\frac{2}{1+u}$. It follows that $u=2\cos^2\theta-1=\cos2\theta$ and $\theta=\frac12\arccos u=\frac\pi4-\frac12\arcsin u$. Thus
$$
\begin{align}
\iint_A\frac{du\ dv}{1-u^2+v^2}
&=2\int_{u=0}^{\Large\frac12}\frac{\arcsin u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\ du+2\int_{u=\Large\frac12}^1\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}\left(\frac\pi4-\frac12\arcsin u\right)\ du\\
&=\bigg[(\arcsin u)^2\bigg]_{u=0}^{\Large\frac12}+\left[\frac\pi2\arcsin u-\frac12(\arcsin u)^2\right]_{u=\Large\frac12}^1\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{36}+\frac{\pi^2}{4}-\frac{\pi^2}{8}-\frac{\pi^2}{12}+\frac{\pi^2}{72}\\
&=\frac{\pi^2}{12}
\end{align}
$$
and the result follows.

Comment: Why does the half disappear in this equation $$-\frac12\int_{x=0}^1\int_{y=0}^1\frac{1}{1-xy}\ dy\ dx=-\iint_A\frac{du\ dv}{1-u^2+v^2}?$$

Comment: @V-Moy Because of the Jacobian. In simple words, when we apply transformation variable technique, let's say from $(x,y)$ to $(u,v)$ then you must use Jacobian in this case, therefore
$$
\int f(x,y)\ dx\ dy=\int f(u,v)\ |J|\ du\ dv,
$$
where $J$ is the Jacobian. Perhaps you are familiar with the transformation variable technique when solving Gaussian integral, we transform the variable from Cartesian to polar coordinate and you will see the factor $r$ appears.

Comment: The answer that you posted makes me learn multivariable calculus more comprehensive first. I need time to understand your answer

Comment: @Tunk-Fey (+1) Brilliant! What made you think of using that 2-variable substitution? Also, I think you have a typo in your very first equation; the RHS should end in $dy$, not $dx$.

Comment: @DavidH Thanks for the compliment, upvote, and checking my answer. Your second answer, $\zeta(2)$, makes me think of using $2$-variable substitution, I remember this technique to obtain $\zeta(2)$ from Robin Chapman's list.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Neat. Is that list on this site? I'd like to read it.

Comment: @DavidH You may take a look in [the OP](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/28329/123277) that I recently answer.

Comment: @Anastasiya-Romanova: In other words,
$$du \wedge dv = \frac{dx+dy}{2}\wedge\frac{dx-dy}{2} = \frac{2\, dy \wedge dx}{4}$$ so $$dy \wedge dx = 2 \, du \wedge dv$$ when we make the substitution.

Answer (score 7):

Substitute $u=x^2$. Then,

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{(1-x^2)}}{x}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{(1-u)}}{\sqrt{u}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\sqrt{u}}\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{(1-u)}}{u}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2{(u)}\bigg{|}_{0}^{1}\\
&=-\frac12\operatorname{Li}_2{(1)}\\
&=-\frac{\pi^2}{12}.
\end{align}$$

I fully anticipate there will be a not small number of people who call this cheating, but it's certainly cheating with style!

---

**Edit:** Here's a slightly more satisfying result. Substitute $u=x^2$ first like before, and next substitute $u=1-e^{-w}$. Then,

$$\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{(1-x^2)}}{x}\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{(1-u)}}{\sqrt{u}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{2\sqrt{u}}\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln{(1-u)}}{u}\mathrm{d}u\\
&=\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{-w}{1-e^{-w}}(e^{-w})\mathrm{d}w\\
&=-\frac12\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{w}{e^w-1}\mathrm{d}w\\
&=-\frac12\Gamma{(2)}\zeta{(2)}\\
&=-\frac12\zeta{(2)}.
\end{align}$$

So now the question becomes do you accept that $\zeta{(2)}=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$. This still leaves a bit to be desired, but a lot more has written about $\zeta{(2)}$ than $\operatorname{Li}_2{(1)}$.

Comment: I was thinking of this but it begs the question "how are these values of $Li_2(x)$ determined?". If it's with the series expansion then it doesn't $really$ change much :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am really sorry, this answer doesn't satisfy me since, in my opinion, I am considering dilog is a series, but I always upvote to those who answer my question. I also notice that with changing variable we will get derivative of beta function, but it's still a dilog function.

Comment: @V-Moy I agree with you, and it doesn't satisfy me either. It's a nice tease though.

Comment: Hey... that's cheating!

Answer (score 5):

Using the [dilogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spence%27s_function) $\mathrm{Li}_2\;$ and the particular values for $0,1,-1\;$you get:
$$\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x}dx= \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)(1+x)}{x}dx=
\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1+x)}{x}dx + \int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x)}{x}dx=
-\mathrm{Li}_2(-x)\Big{|}_0^1 - \mathrm{Li}_2(x)\Big{|}_0^1
=\frac{\pi^2}{12}-\frac{\pi^2}{6} = -\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$

Comment: Heh, I thought some people might cry foul for invoking the value of $\operatorname{Li}_2{(1)}$, but you have invoke $\operatorname{Li}_2{(-1)}$ on top of that. You, sir, are cheating twice as much as me! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am really sorry, this answer doesn't satisfy me since, in my opinion, I am considering dilog is a series, but I always upvote to those who answer my question. I also notice that with changing variable we will get derivative of beta function, but it's still a dilog function.

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x^{2}} \over x}\,\dd x}
=\half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{1 - x} \over x}\,\dd x
=\half\int_{0}^{1}{\ln\pars{x} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
\\[3mm]&=-\,\half\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}
{1 - x^{\mu} \over 1 - x}\,\dd x
=-\,\half\lim_{\mu \to 0}\partiald{\color{#f00}{\Psi\pars{\mu + 1}}}{\mu}
=-\,\half\,\Psi'\pars{1}
\\[3mm]&=-\,\half\,\color{#f0f}{\zeta\pars{2}}
=-\,\half\,\color{maroon}{\pi^{2} \over 6}=\color{#66f}{\large -\,{\pi^{2} \over 12}}
\end{align}

> See [$\underline{\color{#f00}{6.3.22}}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_259.htm),
>   [$\underline{\color{#f0f}{6.4.2}}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_260.htm) and
>   [$\underline{\color{maroon}{23.2.24}}$](http://people.math.sfu.ca/~cbm/aands/page_807.htm).

Comment: Thanks Mr. Felix Marin, but as I said in the previous comment. I consider dilog is a series.

Comment: @V-Moy  There is a [list](http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/rjchapma/etc/zeta2.pdf) that you can check.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Anyway, I have upvoted your answer yesterday

Comment: @V-Moy ${\rm Li}_{2}\pars{z}$ is a series when $\left\vert\,z\,\right\vert \leq 1$. For other values ( besides a branch-cut ) it's found by means of an analytical continuation. However, I didn't use the DiLog: I used the DiGamma function instead. Thanks.

Comment: +1, although the color-coded links unfortunately do not exist or are getting redirected :(

Answer (score 2):

Here is a route without **power series** expansion. Observing that, by the change of variable $x=\sin u$, we have
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=\int_0^{\pi/2}\ln(\cos^2 u)\frac{\cos u}{\sin u}\mathrm{d}u
$$
You may use the Fourier series expansion
$$
\log(\cos u)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k}\frac{1-\cos(2kx)}{k}=\sum_{k=1}^\infty(-1)^{k}\frac{\sin^2(kx)}{k}
$$
to obtain
$$
\int_0^1\frac{\ln(1-x^2)}{x}\mathrm{d}x=2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\! \frac{(-1)^{k}}{k}\!\!\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\sin^2(kx)}{\sin u}\cos u \:\mathrm{d}u=-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\frac11+ ...+\frac1{2k+1}}{2k(2k-1)} =-\frac{\pi^2}{12}.
$$

Comment: The OP states: "prove **without** using series expansion".

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Sorry, I thought 'prove without using **power series** expansion'...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Mr. Olivier Oloa but as Mr. Tunk-Fey said, the proof must not use series expansion. +1 anyway.