# Prove $\int\limits_{]0,\infty[}\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2-1} d\lambda_1(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral, indefinite-integrals

I try to prove the following statement:
$$\int\limits_{]0,\infty[}\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2-1} d\lambda_1(x)=\frac{\pi^2}{4}$$

There is also a clue: $$ \frac{1}{(1+y)(1+x^2y)}=\frac{1}{x^2-1}\left(\frac{x^2}{1+yx^2} - \frac{1}{1+y}\right)$$

$\ $

I tried to compute the Integral by partial integration and I get:

$$\int\limits_{]0,\infty[}\frac{\ln{x}}{x^2-1} d\lambda_1(x) = [ \ln{x}(\frac{1}{2}(\ln{(1-x)}-\ln{(x+1)}))]_0^\infty - \int\limits_{]0,\infty[}\frac{\frac{1}{2}(\ln{(1-x)}-\ln{(x+1)}))}{x} d\lambda_1(x)$$

But I don't thinks this is easier to handle. I thought maybe I could change the logarithm into a series but $x\in ]0,\infty[$ and not $|x-1|<1$.

I can't see the link between the $\ln{x}$ and $$\left(\frac{x^2}{1+yx^2} - \frac{1}{1+y}\right)$$

Why are there 2 variables?

I know how to compute $$\iint\limits_{]0,\infty[} \frac{1}{(1+y)(1+x^2y)}$$

though.

Comment: What is $d\lambda_1(x)$? Is it just integration with respect to the Lebesgue measure?

Comment: It's not mentioned but I would say yes.

Comment: This can be viewed as the [derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) of the [beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function), following a splitting of the integration interval into $(0,1)$ and $(1,\infty),$ and a substitution of the form $x=\dfrac1t$ on the latter.

Comment: i think to use the given hint one have to employ some clever itnegral representation of $\log(x)$. this also explains where the second variable comes from

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Improper Integral $\int_0^1\frac{\ln(x)}{x^2-1}\,dx$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/537903/improper-integral-int-01-frac-lnxx2-1-dx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint that will get you going (I think):
$$
\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{(1+y)(1+x^2y)}\,dy=\frac{2\ln x}{x^2-1}.
$$
Now write things as a double integral, and change the order of integration.